# Store ListBuffer[List[Double]] with Redis

Tags: scala, redis, jedis

I'm using Redis as catching in a play application. With Redis, I can store some string list associated to a key string like in the `case class Cache1` :

```
    case class Cache1(val hostname : String, val port : Int, val timeout : Int) {
    val pool : Pool =
      new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), hostname, port, timeout))
    val j = pool.underlying.getResource
    j.flushAll
    pool.underlying.returnResourceObject(j)


    def set(key : String, value : String) : Unit = pool.withClient { client => 
      client.lpush(key, value)
    }

    def get(key : String) : Option[List[String]] = {
      pool.withClient { client =>
        val l : List[String] =
          Dress.up(client).lrange(key, 0, Dress.up(client).llen(key)-1)
        if(l.length == 0) return None else return Some(l)
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to reproduce the same case class but instead to store `String` as values, I want to store a `ListBuffer[List[Double]]`. But I cannot found in the redis API a way to do that and this is why I ask this question here.

Comment: what's important is how do you want to use the datas? Do you want to get only  one record (ListBuffer[2][3]) or do you want to get a whole listbuffer (ListBuffer[2]) ?

Comment: I need to get the whole `ListBuffer`, not just ony few points from him.

Comment: just to be shure, you will need the whole listbuffer always?

Comment: Yes, always. I want to associate several keys to this kind of data. Like `1 -> ListBuffer(List(1,2), List(3,4)), 2 -> ListBuffer(List(10,10), List(20,20))`.

Answer (score 0):

I will store the whole structure as JSON, and read it as JSON. this is simple  and easy to maintain.

Redis store list

```
object MyJacksonMapper extends JacksonMapper
val jsonListBuffer= MyJacksonMapper.serializeJson(myListBuffer)
Dress.up(client).set("listbuffer",jsonListBuffer)
```

Redis Get

```
val json = Dress.up(client).get("listbuffer") 
val myNewObject = MyJacksonMapper.deserializeJson[ListBuffer](json)
```

Comment: if you have many list, you can store as list, or as SET listbuffer:1, listbuffer:2 .....etc.